# How can I append text to /etc/apt/sources.list from the command line?

Tags: bash

I am new to linux, and just beginning to learn bash. I am using Ubuntu 9.04, and would like to add repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list from the command line. Basically, I would like to do this:

```
sudo echo "[some repository]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

However, even when I use sudo, I get this error:

```
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

How do I avoid this error?

Comment: You need to mention 2 things: 1) Are you on the sudoers list, and is that set up correctly? 2) What are the permissions of your /etc/apt/sources.list file?

Comment: It's better to use a separate file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` rather than modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584066/append-to-etc-apt-sources-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Karmic, you can just use the `add-apt-repository` command, at least for PPAs.

For example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky
```

Comment: add-apt-repository isn't in base, to get it run: `apt-get install software-properties-common`

Comment: And seems now to be available in Debian based systems, so is probably the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 142):

```
echo "[some repository]" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) command is called as the superuser via *sudo* and the *-a* argument tells tee to append to the file instead of overwriting it.

Your original command failed, as the IO redirection with *>>* will be done as the regular user, only your echo was executed with sudo.

Calling a sudo subshell like

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "[some repository]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

works, too as pointed out by others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer--for future reference, where would this belong? Or do you mean that it doesn't belong on this site at all?

Comment: @Matthew As it is not really programming related it probably would be a better fit on serverfault.com once it's open for everybody. Currently it's beta only (http://serverfault.com/beta-access)

Comment: I found this useful as a programmer installing some dependencies; I definitely think that this should be on StackOverflow.

Comment: see also this answer to a similar question (using sed):
[Append text to file from command line without using io redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640152/311288)

Comment: Seems to have a problem when attemmpting it on Amazon VPC/EC2. This is what I get: echo "deb http://deb.theforeman.org/ trusty 1.7" | sudo tee -a  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/foreman.list
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-0-91
deb http://deb.theforeman.org/ trusty 1.7

Comment: If after adding new repo you get a missing GPG key error, see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/235880/how-to-fix-gpg-in-updater

Answer (score 9):

The shell processes ">", "<", ">>" etc itself before launching commands. So the problem is that "sudo >> /etc/foo" tries to open /etc/foo for append before gaining privileges.

One way round this is to use sudo to launch another shell to do what you want, e.g.:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "[some repository]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

Or alternatively:

```
echo "[some repository]" | sudo sh -c 'cat >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

A simpler approach may simply be to use sudo to launch an editor on the /etc/file :)

Answer (score 9):

It's better to use a separate file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` rather than modifying `/etc/apt/sources.list`, as explained in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584066/append-to-etc-apt-sources-list). (Note that the file name MUST end in `.list` or it will be ignored.)

However, if you want to create it using `echo` the issue with permissions remains. You can use `tee` to create it like this:

```sh
echo '[some repository]' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-repository.list >/dev/null
```

or like this:

```sh
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/some-repository.list >/dev/null <<EOF
[some repository]
EOF
```

Note that you don't need `-a` on the `tee` command (because you're not appending).

You can also create the file somewhere else and then copy it into place with:

```sh
sudo cp path/to/some-repository.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Comment: Your comment should be part of your answer, so I suggest you edit the latter.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to do the redirection in a subshell:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "[some repository]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

That way, the `sh` process is executed under `sudo` and therefore has the necessary privileges to open the redirected output to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 3):

Following works for me

```
sudo echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution without using piping, just simple in-place editing:

```
sudo ex +'$put = \"[some repository]\"' -cwq /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The `ex` is equivalent to `vi -e`.

Answer (score -1):

If you were to switch to the root user the same command will work just fine. This is because sudo elevates the priveleges only for the [echo] command and does not elevate the right side of the output redirection.

```
sudo su
echo "[some repository]" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you do it this way be sure to exit from su so that you are not running unnecessary programs as root (superuser)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I tried to better the answer, not sure how it doesn't provide an answer. It would be helpful to know more as to why you came to this conclusion

Comment: Your answer read as just a comment to me instead of answering the question because your question basically just said use Lothar's answer, and if the OP was already a super user, they wouldn't have encountered this issue (misunderstanding of sudo with I/O redirection).

Comment: I see your point, however my answering is just stating that the OP can run that command as superuser instead of using sudo and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

first open or create the file you want to edit it by the following command

> 1- sudo nano file_name
>
> 2- edit the file after it opens
>
> 3- ctrl+x
>
> 4- press 'Y' to say yes

and you are done.

Answer (score -2):

**interesting, 1- remove the file with rm , 2 create the file again with touch, 3 use printf to print formatted, 4 pipe with tee to the file(THIS IS FOR DEBIAN)  replace to your tastes and likes**

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo chmod +rwx /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo printf "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```