# Append to /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm creating some scripts to streamline application installations and I need to append to the end of /etc/apt/sources.list

This code below append to files in ~ but not in /etc/apt/

```
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu karmic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

**@meder**

I have tried these following commands with no luck:

```
sudo echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu karmic main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
#===---
sudo sh "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu karmic main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This will work:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu karmic main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list"
```

However, instead of editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`, it is simpler to add a new `*.list` file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

For example,

```
echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/person/ppa/ubuntu karmic main' >/tmp/myppa.list
sudo cp /tmp/myppa.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
rm /tmp/myppa.list
```

Comment: FYI: whoever edited the `sudo cp + rm` to a `mv`: don't do that. The reason for `cp` is to use root's permissions, whereas with `mv` the file will end up with the current user's permissions.

Answer (score 3):

**make sure to have a backup file**

```
echo "foo" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

However, I would *really* recommend you create a new .list and then use this method to append, store it in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: I think the last time I did something I had to rely on `tee` command, I forget the exact way I did it though.