# Append text to file from command line without using io redirection

Tags: linux, command-line, file-io

How can we append text in a file via a one-line command without using io redirection?

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem (http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341), why do you need append without redirection?

Comment: There are plenty of tools for file manipulaton including Perl, sed (see below), awk, tee -a, etc.

Comment: @Joel : could be true. I asked the question for a colleague, and really don't know what the exact problem is.

Comment: Typically useful when manipulating files with sudo (the IO are under the user's environment), and you sometimes have a limited set of tools allowed via sudo.

Comment: one scenario is cmake execute_process() which does not launch intermediate shell.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you don't mind using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) then,

```
$ cat test 
this is line 1
$ sed -i '$ a\this is line 2 without redirection' test 
$ cat test 
this is line 1
this is line 2 without redirection
```

As the documentation may be a bit long to go through, some explanations :

- `-i` means an inplace transformation, so all changes will occur in the file you specify
- `$` is used to specify the last line
- `a` means append a line after
- `\` is simply used as a delimiter

Comment: I get `sed: -i may not be used with stdin` on macOS 13.3 bash shell.  Probably cos of https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243111/259453

Comment: @volvox, on MacOS, the `-i` option requires a parameter: the extension to use to backup the original file. If you don't want a backup, provide an empty string: `sed -i '' '$ a\this is line 2 without redirection' test`. The error message is explained by the regex being used as parameter to `-i`, the file name as regex and therefore, no parameter for the file.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to tack something on by hand, then the `sed` answer will work for you. If instead the text is in file(s) (say file1.txt and file2.txt):

Using Perl:

`perl -e 'open(OUT, ">>", "outfile.txt"); print OUT while (<>);' file*.txt`

N.B. while the `>>` may look like an indication of redirection, it is just the file open mode, in this case "append".

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `--append` feature of `tee`:

```
cat file01.txt | tee --append bothFiles.txt 
cat file02.txt | tee --append bothFiles.txt
```

Or shorter,

```
cat file01.txt file02.txt | tee --append bothFiles.txt
```

I assume the request for no redirection (`>>`) comes from the need to use this in `xargs` or similar. So if that doesn't count, you can mute the output with `>/dev/null`.

Comment: Piping will also step out of xargs.. So not much better than `>>`, the best approach here is using `sh -c`

Comment: @Tofandel, I meant before `xargs`. You can pipe as much as you want before `xargs`; but `>>` will require you to end the pipe, which then can't continue to `xargs`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'a|BRAVO' -cx file
```

1. `a` append text
2. `x` save and close

Comment: I like the approach in this answer, but it doesn't seem to append to the file. A simple example like this: for fidx in $(seq 1 6); do  ex -sc "a|Something${fidx}" -cx test.txt; done  produces text that is not ordered:cat test.txt
Something2
Something1
Something3
Something4
Something5
Something6.  How do I make it go to the end of the file before appending? Interestingly, it only seems to happen for the first two lines of an empty file. If I run the example multiple times everything is ordered correctly.

Comment: Try putting a $ before the a, which references the end of the file:

 ex -sc "$a|Something${fidx}" -cx test.txt

Answer (score 2):

On Linux/GNU systems, the simplest and cleanest solution is:

```
dd of=oldfile oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

Simple and clean, because no quoting or backslashitis is required.

Unfortunately, this also doesn't work on BSD (and so, on Darwin), because their `dd` has no `oflag` . Argh! Can anyone suggest how to do it with the BSD `dd` ?