# How do I append text to a file?

Tags: shell, file, text, file-io, append

What is the easiest way to append text to a file in Linux?

I had a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640011/append-text-to-file-from-command-line-without-using-io-redirection), but the accepted answer uses an additional program (`sed`) I'm sure there should be an easier way with `echo` or similar.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
cat >> filename
This is text, perhaps pasted in from some other source.
Or else entered at the keyboard, doesn't matter. 
^D
```

Essentially, you can dump any text you want into the file. CTRL-D sends an end-of-file signal, which terminates input and returns you to the shell.

Comment: How can i do this when the file need root permission?

Comment: @UselesssCat when something goes "permission denied", I re-check whatever command I'm running and then use `sudo !!` - which executes the last command with `sudo` prepended. I recently found out this also works with `nano` etc (by accidentally trying to `nano nano auth`...)

Comment: if you need to use sudo or use this in a script refer to my [follow up to this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43423683/1048805) below.

Comment: I didn't know cat could be used like this! Like writing a journal entry. Also didn't know about what ctrl-d does. Thank you!

Comment: @Sandra - Did not use `!!` before, awesome. So often I do stuff like `cat /var/log/apache/error.log` and get permission denied. This could also be done with an id from the history e.g `sudo !1419`, this will execute the command at line `1419` in the history as sudo.

Answer (score 240):

How about:

```
echo "hello" >> <filename>
```

Using the `>>` operator will append data at the end of the file, while using the `>` will overwrite the contents of the file if already existing.

You could also use `printf` in the same way:

```
printf "hello" >> <filename>
```

Note that it can be dangerous to use the above. For instance if you already have a file and you need to append data to the end of the file and you forget to add the last `>` all data in the file will be destroyed. You can change this behavior by setting the `noclobber` variable in your `.bashrc`:

```
set -o noclobber
```

Now when you try to do `echo "hello" > file.txt` you will get a warning saying `cannot overwrite existing file`.

To force writing to the file you must now use the special syntax:

```
echo "hello" >| <filename>
```

You should also know that by default `echo` adds a trailing new-line character which can be suppressed by using the `-n` flag:

```
echo -n "hello" >> <filename>
```

**References**

- [`echo(1) - Linux man page`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)
- [`noclobber variable`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-keep-file-safe-from-overwriting.html)
- [`I/O Redirection`](http://linux.die.net/Intro-Linux/sect_05_01.html#sect_05_01_02)

Comment: In general, I like this more than the accepted answer that uses `cat`, but you'd better be careful with making sure to use `>>` instead of `>`!

Comment: @sixty4bit - Totally agree, but I think you always must know what you're doing when working with a shell or else you might do something like `sudo rm -r /` =)

Comment: better `sudo rm -r /` than `sudo rm -rf /`! ^_^ Is there a flag that would ask for confirmation before overwriting the contents of an existing file with `>`? Aliasing that to always use such a flag seems like it would be a good idea.

Comment: @sixty4bit - You can add `set -o noclobber` in your `.bashrc` then you cannot overwrite an existing file without using the special syntax `echo "hello" >| <filename>`

Comment: can you give an example where the file is called, say "myFile.txt" or something? I'm not sure if it's <filename> or filename in your example

Comment: <filename> is just a placeholder for a filename so it should be echo ”hello” >> myfile.txt for example.

Comment: If I wanted to do this, but for a file that requires `sudo` permissions to write to, how would you write that command out? EDIT: Nevermind, found out how to do it using `tee` https://superuser.com/a/136653/59729

Comment: `sudo bash -c "echo hello >> <filename>"` =)

Answer (score 32):

Other possible way is:

```
echo "text" | tee -a filename >/dev/null
```

The `-a` will append at the end of the file.

If needing `sudo`, use:

```
echo "text" | sudo tee -a filename >/dev/null
```

Comment: Why the >/dev/null at the end?

Comment: The `>/dev/null` at the end prevents "text" to be shown in your console.

Answer (score 22):

Follow up to accepted answer.

You need something other than [CTRL-D to designate the end if using this in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459219/how-to-insert-ctrld-into-my-linux-script). Try this instead:

```
cat << EOF >> filename
This is text entered via the keyboard or via a script.
EOF
```

This will append text to the stated file (not including "EOF").

It utilizes a [here document (or heredoc)](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

However if you need sudo to append to the stated file, you will run into trouble utilizing a heredoc due to I/O redirection if you're typing directly on the command line.

This variation will work when you are typing directly on the command line:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat << EOF >> filename
This is text entered via the keyboard.
EOF'
```

Or you can use `tee` instead to avoid the command line sudo issue seen when using the heredoc with cat:

```
tee -a filename << EOF
This is text entered via the keyboard or via a script.
EOF
```

Comment: I have been using `cat << 'EOF' >` for years and didn't know about `cat << 'EOF' >>` to append! Thanks