# how to insert ctrl+d into my linux script?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, cat

I want to make the following commands:

> cat > template.txt
>   [enter in the terminal]
>   text
>   [Ctrl+d in the terminal]

in a script.

Is there a way to tell the script to do enter\Ctrl d?
Is there a way to create a file and write to it in script?

I didn't find anything that worked for me.

Thanks.

Comment: This problem doesn't seem related to c. What script do you use? Bash? Zsh? Perl? Python? Ruby? Other?

Comment: Related question [Representing EOF in C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389518/representing-eof-in-c-code)

Answer (score 8):

A [Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) is kind of like a script version of what you're talking about, I think, although it is not entirely clear to me from your description.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > template.txt <<- EOF
    Here
    is some 
    text.
EOF
```

Ctrl-D itself *is* the EOF character, ASCII 4.

Comment: Be careful with this construction because it is whitespace senstitive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/485567/unexpected-end-of-file

Answer (score 1):

When you want an interactieve user enter lines and add them to your file until the user enters an ^D you can use the next script:

```
echo "Please give input"

while read -r line; do
            echo "Enter next line or ^D"
            echo "${line}" >> template.txt
done
echo "After loop"
```

You do not have to check for ^D, that will be recognized by read without doing something extra.So you do not need to use `CTRL-V CTRL-D` in `vi`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  How should the script know when your user is finished entering text?