# sending email with ssmtp and bash script

Tags: bash, email

I m new to bash scripting.

I have this command line to send an email with sstmp from the terminal:

```
{
    echo To: user@gmail.com
    echo From: user@gmail.com
    echo Subject: "[Alert]"
echo 'McDonalds now offers vegan burgers and vegan ice cream!'
} | ssmtp user@gmail.com
```

I would like to execute this in a bash script.
Can someone tell me how this is best done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've read other articles here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459219/how-to-insert-ctrld-into-my-linux-script).  The Control-D is actually the keystroke for end of file (EOF).  I've written a bash script that sends using SSMTP.  Give this a try:

```
SUBJECT="TEST TEST TEST"
CONTENTS="This is an email!"

/usr/sbin/ssmtp -t << EOF
To: recipient@xxx.xxx
From: sender@xxx.xxx
Subject: $SUBJECT

$CONTENTS

Cheers,
Me
EOF
```

The [-t](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp) in SSMTP parses the email and if it finds a valid To:, CC: or Bcc: then it uses those addresses.  Just make certain you have your ssmtp config good to go before going this far. Likewise, your ssmtp executable may be located in a different place, adjust accordingly.