# sed: -i may not be used with stdin on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, sed

I am using a bison parser in my project. When I run the following command:

```
sed -i y.tab.c -e "s/  __attribute__ ((__unused__))$/# ifndef __cplusplus\n  __attribute__ ((__unused__));\n# endif/"
```

I get this error
sed: -i may not be used with stdin

The command works fine in linux machines. I am using Mac OS X 10.9. It throws an error only on mac os x. I am not sure why. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the "-e" flag, and put "y.tab.c" at the end of the line.  Like this: `sed -i "s/.../" y.tab.c

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to put the input file as the last parameter.

```
sed -i -e "s/  __attribute__ ((__unused__))$/# ifndef __cplusplus\n  __attribute__ ((__unused__));\n# endif/" y.tab.c
```

Comment: For me the -e flag is adding a literal "-e" to the end of the file extension of the output file which is a copy of the input file.

Comment: @John That is not at all what the -e does.  It basically says use the following as a script.

Comment: I am not using GNU sed. Maybe that's the reason? I ran that command three times and every time the file was named `file.txt-e`

Comment: @John https://ss64.com/osx/sed.html.  What OS are you using?  What do you get for the '-e' option when you type 'man sed'?

Comment: I am on macOS "-e command
             Append the editing commands specified by the command argument to
             the list of commands."

Comment: @John From sed docs, "Because -i takes an optional argument, it should not be followed by other short options". What's happening is that `-i -e` is causing `-i` to treat `-e` as the input to `-i`. You need to either explicitly supply an argument to `-i` (`-i '' -e`) or specify the `-e` flag before the `-i` flag (`-e -i` or `-ei`).

Answer (score 60):

The problem is that Mac OS X uses the BSD version of `sed`, which treats the `-i` option slightly differently. The GNU version used in Linux takes an optional argument with `-i`: if present, `sed` makes a backup file whose name consists of the input file plus the argument. Without an argument, `sed` simply modifies the input file without saving a backup of the original.

In BSD `sed`, the argument to `-i` is required. To avoid making a backup, you need to provide a zero-length argument, e.g. `sed -i '' y.tab.c ...`.

Your command, which simply edits `y.tab.c` with no backup in Linux, would attempt to save a backup file using 'y.tab.c' as an extension. But now, with no other file in the command line, `sed` thinks you want to edit standard input in-place, something that is not allowed.

Comment: `sed -i '' file` works on OSX, but it's not portable. It fails on at least Cygwin and probably Linux. `sed -i'.bak' file` is the most portable syntax I could find, but then you need to do `rm file.bak` at the end.

Comment: Neither form is portable, because the POSIX standard doesn't specify a `-i` option. For true portability, you need to handle the temporary file yourself: `sed '...' file > file.new; mv file file.bak; mv file.new file`.

Comment: '' after the -i worked for me in MACOS 14.0

Answer (score 33):

**From the sed manpage:**

> -i extension
>      Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.
>      If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It
>      is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
>      editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situ-
>      ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

The solution is to send a zero-length extension like this:

```
sed -i '' 's/apples/oranges/' file.txt
```

Comment: Worked as intended and replaced all strings on a json file. Even with '['or ']' didn't need to escape. My expression: sed -i '' 's/wow/][/' wow.json

Answer (score 11):

*Piggy-backing off of @chepner's explanation for a quick-and-dirty solution:*

Install the version of sed that'll get the job done with `brew install gnu-sed`, then replace usages of `sed` in your script with `gsed`.

*(The homebrew community is fairly cognizant of issues that can arise of OS X built-ins are overridden unexpectedly and has worked to not do that for most alternate-distro commands.)*

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, I wanted to

- [find](/questions/tagged/find) all .tex files in a directory &
- [xargs](/questions/tagged/xargs) [these into](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23526919/9592557) [sed](/questions/tagged/sed),
- [to add something as the first line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533736/9592557) of all the files.

As [Slipp D. Thompson suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29503037/9592557), I used `gsed` like below, in macOS, which is similar in linux (remove the `g` from `gsed`):

```
find . -name "*.tex" -print0 | xargs -0 gsed -i '1s/^/% !TEX spellcheck = en-US \n/'
```

Works as intended