# Prevent sed from creating a temporary file

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sed

I'm injecting a proxy variable into a shell script. I have to escape the string as there is a space in between.

```
sed -i -e 's#UseConcMarkSweepGC#UseConcMarkSweepGC $PROXY_ARGS#g' ${TEST_HOME}/bin/test.sh
```

Now this is always generating another file ith `-e` at the end, so I end up with `test.sh` and `test.sh-e`. Both are the same. Currently I'm doing

```
rm test.sh-e
```

right after `sed` which is working fine. I'm wondering if there is a way to not generate a temporary file at all? I can't remove the `-e` as I'm getting the error `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`.

Comment: You are probably under Mac OS X, are you?

Comment: Yes I'm on Mac OS X

Comment: OK. Then I noticed the behaviour is OS X specific, so I am closing as a duplicate where it is very well explained by chepner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of the order you are placing the flags, if you are under a non-GNU sed that requires `-i` to have an argument:

```
sed -i -e '...'
#   ^^ ^^
#   |   |
#   flag|
#       |
#       value for it
```

Like this, `sed` understands `-e` as the extension of the backup file to create.

Instead, say:

```
sed -e -i '...'
```

Or just be explicit about the extension and set it to null, so that no backup file is created:

```
sed -i '' -e '...'
```

See more information in [sed: -i may not be used with stdin on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243111/1983854).

Comment: On my system I can not reproduce the behaviour unless i write `-i-e` without spaces. On what system does your answer apply?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I guess it is in Mac OS X.