# replace string in class bash and azuredevops (ios xamarin pipeline)

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I am trying to write a bash script to change a string in a class for my azure devops pipeline.But cannot make it work.

Copied the script from 
https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter-build-scripts-examples/blob/master/xamarin/app-constants/appcenter-pre-build.sh

my bash attempt:

1. Added a bash task (inline script)
2. Created an env variable    API_URL with value ="https://production.com/api"
3. My Class to change

   ```
   namespace Core
   {
      public class AppConstant
      {
        public const string ApiUrl = "https://production.com/api";
        public const string AnotherOne="AAA";
      }
   }
   ```

My script

```
    if [ ! -n "$API_URL" ]
    then
        echo "You need define the API_URL variable"
        exit
    fi

    APP_CONSTANT_FILE=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyProject/Core/AppConstant.cs

    if [ -e "$APP_CONSTANT_FILE" ]
    then
        echo "Updating ApiUrl to $API_URL in AppConstant.cs"
        sed -i '' 's#ApiUrl = "[a-z:./]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE

        echo "File content:"
        cat $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
    fi
```

why does my variable not change? many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is correct and will get desired output, only remove the dual apostrophes after sed -i:

```
sed -i 's#ApiUrl = "[a-z:./]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
```

However I would also change regexp at least to this, since . (dot) is reserved as any character in regexp:

```
sed -i 's#ApiUrl = "[a-z:\./]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
```

Or even to this (in order to take whatever characters between quotes):

```
sed -i 's#ApiUrl = "[^"]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
```

Test:

```
$ cat > developer9969.txt
namespace Core
{
   public class AppConstant
   {
     public const string ApiUrl = "https://production.com/api";
   }
}

API_URL='https://kubator.com/'
APP_CONSTANT_FILE='./developer9969.txt'
sed -i 's#ApiUrl = "[^"]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE

$ cat $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
namespace Core
{
   public class AppConstant
   {
     public const string ApiUrl = "https://kubator.com/";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time I am not familiar at all with bash as I come from windows etc.. if I wanted to replace another constant string that is not a url  would I need to sed -i 's#ApiUrl = "[a-z:./]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE becomes sed -i 's#myconst = "[a-z:]"#myconst  = "'$myconst'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE   basically removing  "./]*

Comment: This is more regular expression question. Basically [] means character class and * means repeat 0 or unlimited times. So that's why regular expression [a-z:./] kind matches Your url. I am saying kind because having full regexp for url is tough. At least in Your case I would repair [a-z:\./]. Dot must be escaped because is alos regexp reserved as any single character. If You would like to match any non empty aplha (both upper, lower case) string I would suggest regexp: ^[A-Za-z]+$ where ^ is beginning, [A-Za-z] both upple lower alpha, + is repeat one or more times, $ is end

Comment: thanks for your help on this one i guess your are right is more about regex which is another issue  i have tried as follows  to replace a const but cannot do it   sed -i 's#AnotherOne = "^[A-Za-z]+$"#AnotherOne = "'$ANOTHERONE'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE .

Comment: That was generic example, in this case use simply: sed -i 's#AnotherOne = "[^"]*"#AnotherOne = "'$ANOTHERONE'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE

Comment: The answer works fine on Linux running GNU sed, but if you want to run this on MacOS which runs BSD sed you have to add the two apostrophes @Kubator removes in the answer. Correct for Mac will be: `sed -i '' 's#ApiUrl = "[^"]*"#ApiUrl = "'$API_URL'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243111/146921