# "sed: -i may not be used with stdin" Error on MacOS

Tags: macos, sed

I'm trying to run this command:

```
$ while :; do clear; curl $(head -5 fullCommands2.txt); sed -i '' -e 1,5d < fullCommands2.txt; sleep 400; done
```

Upon execution I'm given the error "`sed: -i may not be used with stdin`". I've looked several other solutions such as the ones presented here [sed: -i may not be used with stdin on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242932/sed-i-may-not-be-used-with-stdin-on-mac-os-x). However I keep getting the same error no matter how I change it.

How can I get this to run?

Comment: I won't try to reproduce that, but try leaving the open bracket ('<') out.

Comment: learn to read the error messages. All you should need to do is remove the redirection for std-in, i.e. the `<` char ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: I use `macOS` aswell and using `-i` alone never works for me. You need to specify a new extension. Like `sed -i'.extension' …`. This would save the results to both original file and create a new file with your current file plus that extension. I am not sure if its a bug or a desired behaviour. (can't be sure, I use a really old bash version)

Comment: @Mihir, I had tried that as well, however I got the same error. It seems that the "<" was causing the error.