# ERROR: ssl certificate doesn't exist: /home/rsvay/snap/barrier-kvm/2/.local/share/barrier/SSL/Barrier.pem

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, mouse

I am a frequent user of Barrier-kvm. I recently upgraded my server to  Ubuntu 20.04 and started getting error "ERROR: ssl certificate doesn't exist: /home/rsvay/snap/barrier-kvm/2/.local/share/barrier/SSL/Barrier.pem". I was unable to get any answer using key word "Barrier-kvm" and it took me hours to solve the problem. So i want to share my solution.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Copy the path to SSL directory which you can find in your error.
"ERROR: ssl certificate doesn't exist: /home/rsvay/snap/barrier-kvm/2/.local/share/barrier/SSL/Barrier.pem "
In this case : **"/home/rsvay/snap/barrier-kvm/2/.local/share/barrier/SSL/"**

Then run the following commands:

```
cd  "path to your SSL"
mkdir -p Fingerprints
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj /CN=barrier -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout Barrier.pem -out Barrier.pem
openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in Barrier.pem > Fingerprints/Local.txt
sed -e "s/.*=/v2:sha256:/" -i Fingerprints/Local.txt
```

Comment: thank you, sir, you are a scholar, a wizard,  a sage of higher-order, you saved me hours of pain, all I just had to do was add an SSL certificate.

Comment: I got the error "sed: -I or -i may not be used with stdin" but it works anyway... (macOS Monterey 12.0.1)

Comment: On Mac OS Monterey, Barrier is looking for SSL folder in /Users/{User}/Library/Applications Support/barrier/SSL You need to create Fingerprints on the Server, and Client will prompt you if you trust it.

Comment: I would suggest you make it easy to copy paste the commands. The $ sign is a pain

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: WORKED! My Case: I was trying to connect my Mac as a host and Windows as a client. I was getting 'could not use ssl private key' error. Running this routine on the Mac helped. Thanks a ton!

Comment: it didn't work for my initially, but then i noticed that barrier looks for the file name with capital B - it worked

Comment: if you aren't using the snap then  change snap in the path for .local/share

Comment: Using git bash on Windows, I had to add another / in front of the CN in the 3rd line.

Comment: Recent barrier releases use SHA256 ("v2 fingerprint"). The solution should be adapted as follows: `openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in Barrier.pem > Fingerprints/Local.txt` and `sed -i 's/.*=/v2:sha256:/' Fingerprints/Local.txt`.

Comment: If you are trying to run this on macOS you will get the following error for the last line `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`.  Based on the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242932/sed-i-may-not-be-used-with-stdin-on-mac-os-x), you need to rewrite the last line slightly like so: `sed -i '' -e "s/.*=/v2:sha256:/" Fingerprints/Local.txt` .  Don't forget that you need to completely close Barrier and relaunch it for it to correctly load the new certificate files!

Comment: Also, in case anyone else is trying to get a macOS client to connect to a Windows sever, check out my mini-guide [here](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/issues/231#issuecomment-1722070605).  There may be useful info there for anyone struggling in any OS.

Answer (score 8):

You can disable the SSL Fingerprint from the barrier setting in both server and client. Then it will work smoothly.

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Disabling encryption is not a good idea, and not an adequate answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, disabling is not a good idea. But I tried many solutions but didn't work for me. Only this solution work for me.

Answer (score 5):

Rsvay's solution worked for me after I corrected the file name. capitalize the B: change 'barrier.pem' to 'Barrier.pem'

`$ mv ~/.local/share/barrier/SSL/barrier.pem ~/.local/share/barrier/SSL/Barrier.pem`

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04. However the barrier.pem file generated after running the code is case sensitive, I had to change to Barrier.pem and it runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/discussions/1682

The paths may not align but if you follow the steps, you'll get it working. Win 10 & Ubuntu 20.04. Had to go to `~/snap/barrier/<3digit#>/.local/share/barrier/SSL` and created the Fingerprints folder.

Stay in this directory to run the script that is mentioned.

(You have to create a text file Local.txt in the Fingerprints directory but run the script from SSL).